# Proper tagging for language conversion questions

Tags: discussion, tags

How should on-topic language conversion questions be tagged?

Options:

1. source language + destination language
2. only destination language
3. destination language and some other conversion specific tags like [code-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-conversion/info)

I think a source language tag is not needed and possibly confusing (especially for SEO, as tags are added to the title). On the other hand, an expert in both tags may provide a better answer.

Note: Many code conversion questions fall into the "convert this code for me" category, as already discussed in several questions like [Are language conversion questions on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309826/are-language-conversion-questions-on-topic/309834#309834) and [Code Translation Tagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/code-translation-tagging). This post is about tagging properly constructed questions about one concrete feature/function with reasonable amount of details.

Comment: The source language is tangential to the problem: what's the difference between "converting a function that foo the bar from X language to Y language" and "fooring the bar in language Y"? That the first include irrelevant details.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265825/1187415 is about pure translation requests, which are off-topic. This question is about on-topic questions with reasonable amount of details, and therefore not a duplicate of the other one IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, the description in another language is only used to allow those who know that language to make sure the plain description in english of what you want to achieve is correct and sound and complete.

As such, the language you use for that additional description is not relevant to the *actual question*, certainly not to the level of categorizing it, and thus certainly not meriting a tag.