# Am I allowed to ask others to translate code (from Go to Node.js) on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I have a piece of [Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) code, which has to be translated to [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js). I can't manage to translate it, so I need some help. Am I allowed to ask others to translate code on Stack Overflow?

If not, where can I ask?

Comment: Probably not the whole thing, but why not ask a series of more detailed questions about the specific points you're stuck on?

Comment: You can. But make sure to show what code you have; Where you are right now and where you are stuck (But nobody will just translate the code for you without a clear problem statement where you got stuck while trying to translate it yourself).

Comment: Yes, you can ask for this. **However:** It's important that you show what you've tried, and where you got stuck, since "Write my code for me" questions are not really appreciated.

Comment: @JonasCz That's the problem. I have more than 30 lines of code which I don't understand. I can't ask 30 questions.

Comment: @JopHolp there are services on the internet that can do this for you.  Stack Overflow isn't one of them.  \

Comment: @Will Can you give me a name of such a service please? I have searched for it already, but couldn't find one.

Comment: https://www.freelancer.com/

Comment: bing and google and duckduckgo and yahoo and

Answer (score 14):

No, it would not be appropriate to just dump some code and ask that it be translated.

If you're running into a specific problem while in the process of translating some code, you could potentially create a question in which you provide a small snippet of code from one language, explain how you're attempting to replicate that functionality in another language, and describe the *specific* problems that you have having with your solution, and how it differs from the intended behavior.

Answer (score 7):

To quote myself in [a related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316809/proper-tagging-for-language-conversion-questions#comment307225_316809):

> The source language is tangential to the problem: what's the difference between "converting a function that foo the bar from X language to Y language" and "fooring the bar in language Y"? That the first include irrelevant details.

What you need to ask isn't "How to translate this Go to Node.js?", but "How to do this in Node.js?". Of course, you should also have investigated how to do the task you want to do in Node.js, otherwise you will be met with downvotes.