# Why do we have [sql-to-linq-conversion]

Tags: discussion, tags

Why do we have [sql-to-linq-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-to-linq-conversion)? To me asking people to convert code is off-topic. Here is a discussion about language conversion: [Are language conversion questions on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309826/are-language-conversion-questions-on-topic/309834#309834)

Most of these questions lack the required details such as table structure or model structure. It also seems like a meta tag with the word conversion.

Comment: It is most definitely not a meta tag since it describes the content of the question.  Now just because it isn't a meta tag though, doesn't automatically make it a useful tag.

Comment: @psubsee2003 we used to have the homework tag and that was deemed meta and it described the content of the question.

Comment: No, the homework tag described the type of question.  It didn't tell me anything about what the question was about.  This tag tells me that it is about a linq-to-sql conversion.

Comment: The linked answer points out one case in which conversion questions are valid: when you have code that is converted, and run into a specific problem. Mostly that would just be a problem with the target language. But LinQ resembles SQL. A problem in translating SQL to LinQ (or vice versa) might well be due to subtle differences between the languages.

Comment: theres also this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316809/proper-tagging-for-language-conversion-questions

Comment: @psubsee2003 what difference there is between reading the title/body of the question (which, IMO, has more context) and having a tag specifically for it?

Comment: Fun fact, [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-to-linq-conversion/topusers) haven't answered a question in ages...

Comment: @Braiam unless I am misunderstanding your comment, read my first comment.  My complaint is that it is not a meta tag as mentioned in the post.  I never said it was a useful tag.

Comment: @psubsee2003 but it comes across that way... nuances matters

Comment: I would have thought that code conversion was well within the topic of SE.